# Supervised Descent Method (SDM)

Tags: image, video, image-processing, feature-extraction

Can someone explain briefly how SDM (Supervised Descent Method) for Feature Extraction works?
I searched a lot on the Internet but couldn't found what I was looking for.

Is it only for feature extraction in videos, or can it be used in both videos and images?

If someone can explain, it would be of great help.

Comment: After searching, it seems to be a **custom** algorithm for extracting features.  It is not a universal feature extraction method and it seems to be applied just to facial features.  Did you look at this paper? http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590v/13au/intraface.pdf

Comment: Thank You for the link ! I only need the facial features. I've been looking for the code and the explanation but I haven't been able to find any. I'm looking for its implementation in C++/openCV. Do you know any link to such ?

Comment: All I have been able to find is the paper that links to SDM.  As such, I don't believe there is any code presently.

Comment: Here is the explanation given by the author.
http://humansensing.cs.cmu.edu/xxiong/sdm.html

Answer (score 1):

SDM is a method to align shapes in images. It uses feature extractors (SIFT and HoG) in the process, but is not a feature extractor.
Similar methods are ASM, AAM or CLM, but SDM has better performance and accuracy.

In the case of SDM, in the training process, the system learns some descent vectors from a initial shape configuration (different from the shapes in the database) to the database sets. Those vectors have the hability of fitting a new initial configuration with the face shape in the image you want to fit in.

This link can help you to learn more about it: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0601v1.pdf

About the code, there is some demo samples in the main page of [IntraFace](http://www.humansensing.cs.cmu.edu/intraface/) but if you are looking for the code, I don´t think you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vl_sift for beginning its working even more precise then their original descriptor however its not fast as their descriptor for real time implementation. 
Regarding to their implementation no code were released so far. They are using some specialized version with very fast histogram calculation.